# Does Box2d work on Xbox?

Tags: xna, box2d, xbox

I'm developing a game in XNA. It would be nice for it to be compatible with Xbox. Does Box2d work on Xbox? Is there some way to include any third party libraries I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a port called [Box2dx](http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/) which works on the Xbox. Read up on [this discussion](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3324) for some interesting performance aspects of the library.

Comment: That thread looks informative. Thanks! I hope I don't run into any issues like that, though.

Comment: Hopefully, others have integrated those perf improvements into the library. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) is built on a port of Box2D and contains several features not included in the Box2D core including:

- Continuous collision detection (with time of impact solver)
- Contact callbacks: begin, end, pre-solve, post-solve
- Convex polyons and circles.
- Multiple shapes per body
- Dynamic tree broadphase
- Fast broadphase AABB queries
- Collision groups and categories
- Sleep management
- Contact, friction, and restitution
- Stable stacking with a linear-time solver
- Revolute, prismatic, distance, pulley, gear, mouse joint, and other joint types
- Joint limits, motors, and friction
- Controllers (gravity, force generators)
- Tools to decompose concave polygons, find convex hulls, boolean operations and [more](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation).